# stopping rect from moving moveip pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My problem in Pygame is i don't understand how to stop a Rect from moving after move_ip(+2.0) in my game_loop. i need the rect to stop at a certain point on the screen. i've tried to stop the Rect by putting an if statement under it reading; if time_bar == pygame.rect(0,200,100,80): time_bar.move_ip(0,0). but that didin't work. pls help!!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_height = 900
display_width = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
orange = (255, 153, 0)
red = (255,0,0)

gamedisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_height,display_width))
pygame.display.set_caption('ye boy')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
gamedisplay.fill(white)
pygame.display.flip()
time_bar = pygame.Rect(900,200,100,80)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def game_loop():
  font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 90)
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()
  text = ''
  intro = True

  while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            return

    # drawing the input box
    gamedisplay.fill(white)

    # time bar and its function
    pygame.draw.rect(gamedisplay, red, time_bar)
    time_bar.move_ip(-2,0)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

game_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `speed_x` variable and pass it to `move_ip`. Set `speed_x` to 0 when the x-coordinate is less than 0 to stop the rect.

```
speed_x = -2

while intro:
    # ...
    # Set the speed to 0 if the x-coordinate is <= 0.
    if time_bar.x <= 0:
        speed_x = 0

    time_bar.move_ip(speed_x, 0)
```

Alternatively (or additionally), you could set the position of the rect to 0 once it reaches that position:

```
if time_bar.x <= 0:
    time_bar.x = 0
```